# Messages are not removed from the Camel route queue

Tags: java, apache-camel

Please tell a newbie how to build the route correctly, everything seems to work, but processed messages are not removed from the queue.

```java
@Startup
@CamelAware
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    @Resource(mappedName = "java:/ConnectionFactory")
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        JmsComponent component = new JmsComponent();
        component.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);

        getContext().addComponent("jms", component);

        from("timer://foo?fixedRate=true&period=60000")
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET"))
            .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"))
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, constant("projectCode=200"))
            .to("https://serv:port/rest/testgetprojectlist")
            .convertBodyTo(String.class)
            .to("jms:queue:queue_name?concurrentConsumers=10&acknowledgementModeName=CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE")
            .to("file:///opt/tmp/?fileName=tempOut.txt&charset=UTF-8")
            .log("we are in here with this message ${body}");

    }
}
```

Comment: You are producing messages using: to("jms") but you never consume them from("jms"). Since there are no consumers it will not remove the messages.

Comment: @Namphibian thanks for the answer, yes I created a consumer and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Try this out..

Adding acknowledgementModeName=CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE makes Camel only remove the message when the route is finished successfully:

from("activemq:some.queue.name?acknowledgementModeName=CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE")

Camel is also locking these messages to prevent other Camel instances or threads from processing the same message.